# Rotate an image based on reference point

Tags: ios, uiimageview, xcode6, image-rotation

I have the code that will rotate my image like a "spinner" based on its geometric center... however because the image itself is asymmetrical, i wish to rotate it about a particular reference point in terms of (x,y) coordinates of the UIImageView. 
Here is my current code that rotates the image:

```
self.spinnerView.center=CGPointMake(self.spinnerView.center.x, self.spinnerView.center.y);
self.spinnerView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation (angle);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// why u change center of View on itself??? o_O What you want with it?
self.spinnerView.center=CGPointMake(self.spinnerView.center.x, self.spinnerView.center.y);
```

And read a documentation:

> The origin of the transform is the value of the **center property, or
>   the layer’s anchorPoint property if it was changed.** (Use the layer
>   property to get the underlying Core Animation layer object.) The
>   default value is CGAffineTransformIdentity.

so :

```
self.spinnerView.layer.anchorPoint=CGPointMake(0, 0);
self.spinnerView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
```

was written about anchorPoint:

> You specify the value for this property using the unit coordinate
>   space. The default value of this property is (0.5, 0.5), which
>   represents the center of the layer’s bounds rectangle. All geometric
>   manipulations to the view occur about the specified point.